# How to add vocabulary terms to a taxonomy category

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to get my module to install a vocabulary on enable/install but something about adding terms to it isn't working. any idea why this function isn't working?

```
function _vocabulary_add_items() {
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('usertype');
  if($vocabulary === TRUE) {
    $terms = array(
        (object) array(
            'vid' => $vocabulary->vid,
            'name' => t('Economy'),
            'description' => t('Basic user account'),
            'format' => '', // default
            'weight' => 0, // default
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => $vocabulary->machine_name, // optional
        ),
        (object) array(
            'vid' => $vocabulary->vid,
            'name' => t('Deluxe'),
            'description' => t('Deluxe user account'),
            'format' => '', // default
            'weight' => 0, // default
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => $vocabulary->machine_name, // optional            
        ),
        (object) array(
            'vid' => $vocabulary->vid,
            'name' => t('Ultimate'),
            'description' => t('Ultimate user account'),
            'format' => '', // default
            'weight' => 0, // default
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => $vocabulary->machine_name, // optional            
        )
    );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        taxonomy_term_save($term);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load()` returns an `object` or `FALSE`. You're checking for exactly `TRUE` by using `===`.

Any of the following should work (sorted by my preference):

```
if ($vocabulary) {
if (is_object($vocabulary)) {
if ($vocabulary !== FALSE) {
if ($vocabulary == TRUE) { // only two equal signs here
```

Comment: I've tried each of those options but it seems not to create the terms still.

Comment: Could it be the way i have the terms nested in the array?

Comment: I just tried your code using `if ($vocabulary) {` and it worked great. `hook_install()` is only called on first installation. So if you're just disable/enable to test w/o uninstalling first, it won't work.

Comment: I've been using the devel reinstall option. I believe this uninstalls and then installs.

Comment: Great thanks rocketeerbkw seems to work now. I think it was my conditional statement in a previous function that was preventing it from looping over the results.